# Should I explicitly declare static methods in Java 8 interfaces as "public static" instead of "static" only?

Tags: interface, java-8, static-methods

Looking at some interfaces in the Java 8 APIs (Example: Stream) I saw that static methods are declared as public static, but default and abstract methods are not. From a technical point of view if I omit the public in static methods of interfaces I got something different of public access modifier?

Comment: The bigger question is why does it bother you?

Comment: Possibly because they were refactored from a utility class `Streams` that was removed from JDK 8 prior to its release.

Comment: I'm used to write my code based on what I read in the own Java APIs because I believe that Oracle engineers follow the recommendations of themselves when they say that it is a "discouraged practice". So the point is not about it bother me. I want to know from a technical point of view if I omit the public in static methods of interfaces I got something different of public access modifier.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Java 8 Language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) states clearly that:

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public. It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style,
>   to redundantly specify the public modifier for a method declaration in
>   an interface.

However, there is a [new feature coming with Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072872) consisting in supporting private interface methods. These private methods will be useful  for reusing a block of code that default methods could benefit from.

So I think that the usage of **public** in the Java APIs is an anticipation of this change to make method visibility explicit for the sake of precision. Consequently, even if Java 8 does not encourage it, you can consider this it as a new best practice.
Further readings [here](http://blog.joda.org/2016/09/private-methods-in-interfaces-in-java-9.html).